# Modify src of all script in a html page before the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to rewrite all src of all script tags in a html page before the js scripts are loaded using javascript?

I tried to use `<plaintext>` tag but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: What's the use case? If you execute your JavaScript first you might be able to do it with a `MutationObserver` listening for all script nodes and edit them while they get read.

Comment: are you want to prevent of loading all scripts?

Comment: I want to load them through a proxy

Comment: @E.Sundin I understood that the mutation observer event will be fired when the script is encountered by the parser but I cannot modify the element being added to the HTML

Comment: If you have access to the page then why not modify all the `src`s of the script you use? If you don't have access then would a chrome plugin solution suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I made a working example of what you want. It uses MutationObserver to listen for node changes to body and changes the src of all scripts when found. It demands that your JavaScript is executed before the targeted files.

```html
<script>
  // select the target node
  var target = document.body;

  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log(mutation.type)
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script')).forEach(s => {
        if (s.src && s.src.indexOf('jquery') !== -1) {
          s.src = "" // this resets the script src
        }
      });

      console.log('Jquery is loaded:', typeof $ !== 'undefined')
    });
  });

  // configuration of the observer:
  var config = {
    childList: true
  };

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(target, config);
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js?hej"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js?oj"></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand. According to the documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver the event is fired after the dom is changed so it starts downloading the script from the original src and I cannot stop it.

Comment: @GiuseppePes I thought the same but in my example it seems to have blocked the execution of the script. I wasn't sure it was going to work until I tested it.

Comment: If you look at the network console the request is made, the script is fetched but it looks like it doesn't execute it.